# How do I execute cmd commands through a bat file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to create a .bat to put together with my setup system to install a network driver, but I have some difficulties in creating the bat.

This .bat needs:

1. execute a cmd with administrator privileges
2. run this command: netcfg.exe -v -l networkbll_lwf.inf -c s -i nt_networkbll
3. exit

The folder for all files location is: c:\Windows\System\Drivers.

Comment: Where did you get to and where did you got stuck? Can you provide existing code?

Comment: Use Notepad or another plain-text editor to create a .bat file script. Put the commands needed into the file and save it. Right-click on it and choose `Run as administrator`. If you have questions, copy and paste the text of your .bat file script into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use another batch file first to launch the second with admin rights.

In the first use

```
runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator batchfilename.bat
PAUSE
```

and write the needed command in another bat file